# MudBlazor: Prevent closing MudDialog when clicking on OK button

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

Is there a way to prevent closing of the `MudDialog` when the user click the OK button? I would like to keep the dialog opened while a action is performed.

```cs
private async Task OpenMyDialogAsync()
{
    var dialog = DialogService.Show<MyDialog>("My Dialog");
    var result = await dialog.Result;


    if (!result.Cancelled)
    {
        // Prevent closing the dialog when user click the OK button
        // to perform an action
    }
}
```

An other idea was to register on an event at the `MyDialog` instance. But the result returned by the `Show()` method don't contain the `MyDialog` instance. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Why close it then? Your "Ok" button has an `OnClick`.

Instead of this:

```cs
<MudButton Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="Submit">Ok</MudButton>
void Submit() => MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(true));
```

Do this:

```cs
<MudButton Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="RunMyStuff">Ok</MudButton>
    
void RunMyStuff(){
    // Run your stuff here
    // Done
    Submit();
}

void Submit() => MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(true));
```

Comment: The problem in your solution is that the business logic should be in the dialog itself. For a reusable component that is not the optimal way. I want to keep the logic outside the component. I would like to have something like the  `FormClosingEventArgs` from WinForms, where you can cancel the event and so prevent the dialog from closing.

Comment: Or you have the business logic in a service/interface and just trigger it from the dialog?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea for an workaround. Thank you for the hint!